# Unable to Remote Desktop into Windows 10 PC

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop

I have a physical Windows 10 machine on my network that I use as a Plex Media Server and Steam machine. It's connected directly via ethernet to my router. All devices on my network are able to use the Plex Media Server both through Plex apps where applicable and through DLNA as well.

When I attempt to remote desktop into this computer from a machine on the same router (a machine that CAN browse it's Plex server), using the same username and password as used for local login, I receive "connection refused" messages. This occurs both from the Microsoft Remote Desktop app on my Mac and the native RDP app in Windows 7.

What I've done so far:
I have fully disabled Windows Firewall on this machine.
I have enabled remote connections for "Everyone".

Beyond those two steps, I'm at a loss. That's all I ever had to do on my Windows 7 media server, but since going to 10 I can't RDP. Since Plex works fine and other machines connect, I know it's not a simple network connectivity issue. Assuming there's some setting I can't find in Windows 10 that needs to be handled.

Comment: Are you using Windows 10 Pro, Enterprise, or Home?  Can you provide a screenshot of where you enabled remote connections?

Comment: I'd save all that time and effort looking for a solution and just install teamviewer instead. Much more functionality and its free.

Comment: Have you [enabled](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/setup-use-remote-desktop-windows-10/) [rdp](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/turn-on-remote-desktop-in-windows-vista/)? Not sure what your goals are, but if you anticipate to play games or play media over rdp you will be sadly disappointed by the quality performance.

Comment: Windows 10 Home. Yes, RDP is enabled (just like in the directions posted in the previous comment). Performance isn't an issue, I'm using RDP for specific use cases unrelated to gaming and media streaming.

Comment: Windows 10 Home doesn't support RDP, you need Pro or Ultimate. Suggest you use a third-party VNC solution like TightVNC or No Machine.

Comment: Wow, if it doesn't support RDP why do I have all the RDP options?

Either way, thanks for the recommendation - Teamviewer did the trick.